# How do I prevent a backend script from being accessed by typing in the url?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am playing around learning new things and am currently working on a way to log in and out of my site and only access different pages if I am logged in. I currently have a login form that will log me in. I have a session variable set that can be checked if someone is logged in and if not redirect to a login page. Here is how it works, and my problem. I have a login page that once logged in will direct you to say Home.php. this all works great except, I can go directly to home.php from the url. mysite.com/home.php allows access even if the person is not logged in.

To fix this I have attempted 2 things. I have tried this for Home.php:

```
<?php 

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["Authenticate"])){

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <?php include "structure/header.php" ?>

      <div class="cmsPanel">

       <a href="php/cms/logoutProcess.php">Logout</a>

        <div id="AddEditor">
          <form method="POST" action="php/cms/newEditor.php">
            <input class="loginFields" type="text"  name="name" placeholder="First Name">
            <input class="loginFields" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
            <input type="submit" value="Create New Editor">
          </form>
        </div>

        <div id="manageEditors">

          <div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

            <?php include "structure/footer.php" ?>
</body>

</html>

}
else{

    header("Location: login.php");
}
?>
```

Which did not work. I would end up with a Error 500 and a blank page. So trying to come up with a solution I just figured I could do something like this:

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["Authenticate"])){

    include_once('php/cms/EditorPanel.php');
}
else{

    header("Location: login.php");
}
?>
```

which works, except you could just go to mysite.com/php/cms/Editorpanel.php and bypass the login.This also made me realize that someone could also directly access things like mysite.com/php/cms/newEditor.php and any other backend script that I have on my server. Personally I would like to be able to use the first attempt with having everything on home.php, but I also need to understand how to prevent anyone from accessing other backend scripts on my server.

I thought I could just use htaccess in the cms folder and add Deny from All to it, but this prevents any of the backend scripts to run. Could I use cgi-bin? and if so how exactly do I access it? On my ftp It doesn't allow me to add anything outside of the root directory www. Is there a way designate a new root directory inside of the hosts established root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Home.php is a php script mixed with html, There is no separation. You need to separate your html from your php. close your php tags before begining html. This should help your first issue. As for your second issue of protecting your assets @Pablo Flores answer should point you in the right direction.

```
    <?php 

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["Authenticate"])){
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <?php include "structure/header.php" ?>

      <div class="cmsPanel">

       <a href="php/cms/logoutProcess.php">Logout</a>

        <div id="AddEditor">
          <form method="POST" action="php/cms/newEditor.php">
            <input class="loginFields" type="text"  name="name" placeholder="First Name">
            <input class="loginFields" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
            <input type="submit" value="Create New Editor">
          </form>
        </div>

        <div id="manageEditors">

          <div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

            <?php include "structure/footer.php" ?>
</body>

</html>
<?php
}
else{

    header("Location: login.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I completely looked past that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear the session when the user logged out, and on each page you have to check if the session is empty, maybe you did that but double check the code.

Comment: The first issue is resolved, the problem I am having now is that the backend scripts are exposed if you go directly to them using the url.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that many web frameworks use is using some kind of dispatcher.

So you could have an .htaccess file in the root of your site like the following:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php to dispatch request
RewriteRule . index.php
```

And inside of a directory where you would put the source code you could add an htaccess denying all requests

```
deny from all
```

Inside index.php you just need to parse $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to see which url the user requested and include the files as needed, some kind of router fuctionallity.

Checkout [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/) framework to see a more robust aproach

## EDIT

The most simple thing you could use is the following:

Inside index.php

```
var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);//For debugging purposes, so you could check the url
if(strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],"private.php")){//if the url requested the file private.php inside the private directory
 require_once './private/private.php'; //include the file
}
```

As you can see, the user can't access directly any of the source code, inside the if statement you can add all session validation you want and before that you can pre-process the request. This way you have total controll over every file the user can access

Comment: how exactly do I access any of the files that are in the directory with the deny from all, when I do this I get a 403 error. im thinking that it has to do with the last part of your explaination about the index needing to parse something?

Comment: Thank You! I am trying to use as few frameworks as possible, just so I can understand how things work on their own. Im not by my machine that has the project but I see what is happening and am sure you just solved my issue. If there was a way to accept both answers I definitely would!

Comment: ok so maybe I am doing something wrong? I tried it and nothing changed. So heres what I did. I inserted that bit of code into my editorLogin.php page, and changed the file name in the if file to loginProcess.php and then required the login process like php/cms/private.php. was I supposed to pull the php folder containing all the scripts out of the public folder?

Comment: I created a new question to get more detailed with this issue and include some of the things I have done since posting this one.